# Replace the value of a column which is close match to another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

There is a dataframe as follows:

```
ID   Mat_Des                             Matched_Des                         Price    Score
1    4-STROKE 25HP OB MOTOR FOR GEMINI   4- STROKE 25 HP OB MOTER FOR GEMNI  10000      100
2    OBS for 25HP OBM                    STANDARD TOOL KIT                    5000       94
3    Accessories for 25HP OBM            SERVICE ENGINEERING                  5000       54
4    Standard Tool Kit for 25HP OBM      PBS DOCUMENTATION                    1000
5    OWNER’S MANUAL (IN ENGLISH)
```

The `Score` is derivation from a fuzzy matching logic which matches `Mat_Des` and `Matched_Des` using `fuzz.partial_ratio` and set threshold to 85.
I want a resultant dataframe where `Matched_Des` column would be dropped. But the `Price` would be plotted accordingly. So the resultant dataframe would be

```
ID   Mat_Des                               Price
1    4-STROKE 25HP OB MOTOR FOR GEMINI     10000
2    OBS for 25HP OBM                       5000
3    Accessories for 25HP OBM                 0               
4    Standard Tool Kit for 25HP OBM         5000    
5    OWNER’S MANUAL (IN ENGLISH)              0
```

Please note that for `Mat_Des` "Standard Tool Kit for 25HP OBM" the `Price` is plotted as 5000. Because it was for "Standard Tool Kit" under `Matched_Des`.

To start I want to use a similar approach like:

```
 df['Mat_Des'] = np.where(df['Score']>85, df['Matched_Des'],df['Mat_Des'])
```

But the above approach would replace `OBS for 25HP OBM` by `STANDARD TOOL KIT`.

Any clue on how to address this?

Comment: It is not clear how we would infer from the dataframe that "Standard Tool Kit for 25HP OBM" matches "Standard Tool Kit". It sounds to me that you need to calculate pairwise "scores" to see what is matching what